# defining generic return for a method/function in php with phpdocblock

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpstan, psalm-php

Is there a way to specify that a function will return an object of a specific type, where the type is the string of one of the parameters?

e.g.

```php
/**
 * @return object<$class>
 */
public function create(string $class): object {
 ... some factory stuff
}
```

so that vscode or phpstorm will know that when I do

```php
$myvar = X::create('MyClass');
```

$myvar will be of type MyClass and I'll have the proper intellisense/autocompletion for it?

Comment: I created a bug report for vscode . since it cannot handle Generics properly. 
https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/2144
unless there is some other way to do it for it.

Comment: unfortunately at the current date a team member of vscode's intelephense has anwer `Generics are not currently supported.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could work using templates like this:

```php
/**
 * @template T of object
 * @psalm-param class-string<T> $a
 * @param class-string<T> $a
 * @return T
 */
function foo($a)
{
    return $a;
}
```

But I don't know whether VSCode already supports that. PhpStorm for example doesn't know how to handle the returned value properly

Comment: in your example the parameter `$a` is also the returned instance. I need parameter to be a string that describes the class returned. foo('stdClass') should be inferred as: foo($c:string):stdClass, and foo('DateTime') as foo($c:string):DateTime

Comment: @useless please see my revised code. This time, I've checked it using PHPStan before answering :P

Comment: I had already find that, unfortunately vscode is not recognizing the return type.